sending a message from client while connected to Websocket server in JavaScript
i'm using "ws" package of npm in order to connect to coinex websocket server.
i know that in onOpen function of ws i can send messages to server, but i want to be able to send messages after connecting to server. here is my code:
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import { URL } from 'url';
import { setTimeout } from "timers/promises";


class CoinexWebsocketClient{
    websocket: WebSocket;
    url: string|URL;
    constructor(url: string|URL){
        this.url = url;
    }
    connect(){
        this.websocket = new WebSocket(this.url);
        this.websocket.on('message', this.onMessage);
        this.websocket.on('close', this.onClose);
        this.websocket.on('open', this.onOpen);
        this.websocket.on('error', this.onError);
    }
    onError = (err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    }
    onOpen = ()=>{
        console.log('Connected to server');
        this.websocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            "method":"state.subscribe",
            "params":[
            "BTCUSD"
            ],
            "id":15
            })
        );
    }
    onClose = ()=>{
        console.log('Disconnected from server');
    }
    disconnect(){
        this.websocket.terminate();
    }
    onMessage=(message: string)=>{
        console.log(`Received message from server: ${message}`);
    }
    send(message){
        this.websocket.send(JSON.stringify(message))
    }
    
}

const customFunction = async (coinexWebsocket:CoinexWebsocketClient) => {
    await setTimeout(5000);
    console.log("Waited 5s");
  
    await setTimeout(5000);
    console.log("Waited an additional 5s");
    csws.send(JSON.stringify({
        "method":"kline.subscribe",
        "params":[
          "BTCUSD",
          60
        ],
        "id": 5
      }))
};
let csws = new CoinexWebsocketClient("wss://perpetual.coinex.com/")
csws.connect()
customFunction(csws)

but after timeout reaches and customFunction executes csws.send, my connection gets closed immediately. i want my client be connected to server and send messages using send function while code is running . how can i solve this issue?

You need to remove one of your JSON.stringify() calls. The one in your send() function is failing, because you are passing in a string not an object.

@RayWallace it wasn't throwing any exceptions or errors. how can i see exceptions and errors happening in CoinexWebsocketClient class?

JSON.stringify() seems to be happy enough stringifying a string, but the server on the other end of the websocket would not have been able to convert it back into a useable object. So my guess is it was the server that closed the connection, not your code (well, your code indirectly). In this instance, the error could be seen by looking over your code or by checking the server for errors.

Note that I have never used websockets, so I don't know if the server should have let your code know about the error or not.
